# Distribute workers across several nodes

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

When calling `parpool` are there then any way that I can specify how the workers created should be organised among available nodes in a cluster?

My problem simplified is, say we have two functions, `function1` and `function2`, both of these functions are vectorized and thus uses all available CPU cores.

I now have access to two nodes on a cluster, where I would like to run these two functions. Each node has 24 cores and the cluster have 32 MDCS licenses. So I am interested in creating 2 workers, where one worker is on the first node and the second on the second node, such that I can run `function1` on one node and `function2` on the second node, and let the vectorization fully use the each node.

I cannot just ask for 48 workers as we do not have this many licenses. So I need to distribute the workers among the available nodes.

ALTERNATIVE:

If it is easier, we can also consider a `parfor`-loop

```
parfor 1:M
    %Vectorized calculation
end
```

where each of the workers created by the `parfor` is distributed among the nodes.

Comment: What scheduler are you using? With MJS, there's no documented way to control how tasks are scheduled on nodes - but with most other schedulers such as LSF or Slurm, I think this should be possible.

Comment: We use Slurm as scheduler

Comment: In that case, you should probably ask over on serverfault or somewhere similar how to get your job scheduled as you wish.